# Jack Audio ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, jack

I used to have Jack Server working with 10.10, 11.04, 11.10 but not 12.04 and now 12.10.

I have installed jackd jackd2 qjackctl surfed many forums and even given advice of how to get jack working, but now I am stuck.

```
Tue Nov 27 22:30:46 2012: Saving settings to "/home/shane/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
22:31:19.960 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Tue Nov 27 22:31:19 2012: Starting jack server...
Tue Nov 27 22:31:19 2012: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Tue Nov 27 22:31:19 2012: [1m[31mERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0[0m
Tue Nov 27 22:31:19 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0[0m
Tue Nov 27 22:31:19 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Audio device hw:0,0 cannot be acquired...[0m
Tue Nov 27 22:31:19 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Cannot initialize driver[0m
Tue Nov 27 22:31:19 2012: [1m[31mERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1[0m
Tue Nov 27 22:31:19 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Failed to open server[0m
Tue Nov 27 22:31:21 2012: Saving settings to "/home/shane/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
22:31:22.047 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to install `pulseaudio-module-jack` and ensure the `jackdbus-detect` module is loaded in pulseaudio, for it to release control of the sound device and allow jackd to grab the hardware instead. Or you'll need a secondary audio card or interface for using with jack.

I have a secondary USB audio interface for use with jack and the pro audio tools in my setup, and let pulseaudio keep the internal Intel audio card, for example.

You'll also likely want to install the `linux-image-lowlatency` kernel for better RT processing support with jackd.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I will give that a go and see what the outcome is.

Comment: @shaneo1 what was the resolution?  Did this work for you?

Comment: I had no luck as I only have the internal sound card, which had been working pre 12.04, infact pulseaudio does not work very well with 5.1 surround on my soundcard either again since 12.04 released.

Comment: followed these instructions then went to the setup in Jack audio connection kit then press setup then pressed the arrow to select the correct hardware.
the default did not work.
Thanks all is working now.

Comment: @dobey how do I check if `jackdbus-detect` is loaded in pulseaudio??

Comment: `pactl list modules`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pasuspender`! Like this:

`pasuspender qjackctl`

It "pauses" pulseaudio while qjackctl runs and "respawns" pulseaudio when qjackctl is terminated. *I was having your problem and this solved it for me. Hope it works for you too.*

Comment: That completely froze my X environment. Good that I could kill this command from character console.

Comment: It's "**p**ulse **a**udio suspender". All it should do is stop pulseaudio temporarily & run qjackctl, then when qjacktl exit it would run pulse audio again. It worked fine for me. Try checking that you're up to date? sry for the trouble @CsabaToth